# Finding clusters in string data

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, cluster-analysis

I have surveyed people about which fruit they like to eat (see data below) and I want to see whether there are clusters in the data. Do people who like bananas frequently also like loganberries, say.  There's 23 different types of fruit and 400 respondents.

I would like to conduct the analysis in Python with Pandas, because that's what I know best. If this is a sane option, is there a common approach to this type of problem (there seems to be a lot of conflicting advice)? Does anyone have a recommended approach?

```
Participant | Bananas |  Apples | Kumquats | Loganberries
------------|-------------------------------------------
1           |  Yes   |   No    |   Yes    |    Yes
2           |  Yes   |   Yes   |   No     |    Yes
3           |  Yes   |   No    |   Yes    |    No
4           |  No    |   No    |   No     |    Yes
5           |  Yes   |   No    |   Yes    |    Yes
6           |  Yes   |   Yes   |   No     |    No
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `corr` to get the correlation matrix:

```
out = df.set_index('Participant').replace({'Yes': 1, 'No': 0}).corr()
print(out)

# Output
               Bananas    Apples  Kumquats  Loganberries
Bananas       1.000000  0.316228  0.447214     -0.316228
Apples        0.316228  1.000000 -0.707107     -0.250000
Kumquats      0.447214 -0.707107  1.000000      0.000000
Loganberries -0.316228 -0.250000  0.000000      1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks. That certainly worked and generated data that appears to show some slight correlation. The values are pretty low though: a couple at the 0.6 level and everything else at 0.1-0.2. I'll need to do some reading to work out what level is considered a correlation.

Comment: @user4896331. A correlation score of 1 is a perfect positive match (like Banana-Banana or True and True:)). A correlation score of -1 is a perfect negative match: when one is Yes the other is No (mutually exclusive like True and False). The rest is like quantum mechanics :-)